# WebVTT captions not showing

Tags: html, caption, webvtt, closed-captions

I'm adding captions to a video I recorded, however none of the captions that I created in my captions.vtt file aren't showing. What is wrong with my code?

```
websites.html
<video width="320" height="480" controls>
        <source src="IMG_1771.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <track kind="captions" label="Video Captions" src="captions.vtt"  />
    </video>


captions.vtt
WEBVTT

Title
00:00.000 --> 00:00.300 
Good Morning

Subtitle
00:00.500 --> 00:02.000 
My name is John Doe

Subtitle 2
00:02.500 --> 00:04.000  
And today I will be giving reasons why video enhances websites
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play a subtitle on its own you should always define `default` attribute within the `track` tag to indicate which track is enabled Since you got only one track here you should indicate it as an active one.

Also, As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track) mentioned in the attribute section of `track` tag, whenever you add `kind` attribute to track tag you should indicate `srclang` too and it is necessary.

So the output should be something like this:

```html
<video width="320" height="480" controls>
    <source src="IMG_1771.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track default kind="captions" label="Video Captions" srclang="en" src="captions.vtt"/>
</video>
```

Comment: I've updated my code, but it still doesn't show any of the captions.

Comment: @Angel Did you config your web server correctly? (to support .vtt)

Comment: No, Im testing it offline and using firefox

Comment: @Angel So this might be a `src` referring problem. Could you share your HTML, video, and subtitle directory hierarchy?

Comment: file:///Users/admin/Documents/CPT330/websites.html file:///Users/admin/Documents/CPT330/captions.vtt file:///Users/admin/Documents/CPT330/IMG_1771.mp4

Comment: @Angel I'm not sure if it works but try to use relative path and make your sources like this: `src="./IMG_1771.mp4"` and `src="./captions.vtt"`

Comment: I finally got it working. I had two erros, 1) I was missing a millisecond digit in one of my subtitles. 2) I also had a time confusion where two subtitles had the same time-code.